# Run ansible playbook on specified host and group?

Tags: ansible

Let's suppose that we have host group dev with corresponding group vars.

```
[dev]
host1
host2
```

How to run ansible playbook with a **host3** that is not in group **dev** using CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a host not in inventory with an extra `-i`. You have to use a comma separated list with a trailing comma to make it work:

```
ansible-playbook -i 'my-inventory.ini' -i 'host3,' playbook.yaml
```

I don't know how to associate `host3` with a group like `dev` from the CLI, so if you've got other stuff in the inventory, you could restrict it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i 'my-inventory.ini' -i 'host3,' playbook.yaml --limit 'dev:host3'
```

Of course, that'll only work if your playbook doesn't explicitly need to reference the `dev` group, and uses `all` instead.